# numpy finding indices of good values

Tags: python, numpy

I am a newbie in Numpy.  I want to find indices of elements equal to a set of values.  For example, I know this works:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]])
>>> x
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
>>> x[np.where(x[:,0] == 2)]
array([[2, 3]])
```

But why doesn't this work?  I would imagine it should be a straight-forward extension. No?

```
>>> x[np.where(x[:,0] == [2,4])]
array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Are you looking for the two elements individually, or the sequence of a 2 followed by a 4?

Answer (score 1):

`==` doesn't work like that; when given two arrays of different shape, it tries to broadcast the comparison according to the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

If you want to determine which elements of an array are in a list of elements, you want [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
>>> numpy.in1d(x.flat, [2, 3, 5, 7])
array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=boo
l)
>>> numpy.in1d(x.flat, [2, 3, 5, 7]).reshape(x.shape)
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would want

```
 x[np.where(x[:,0] in [2,4])]
```

which may not actually be valid numpy

```
mask = numpy.in1d(x[:,0],[2,4])
x[mask]
```

as an aside you could rewrite your first condition to

```
x[x[:,0] == 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that you meant that you want to find rows where the first element is equal to some special value. The way you have stated it I think that you meant `x[:,0] in [2,4]`, not `x[:,0] == [2,4]`, which will still not work in `np.where()`. Instead, you would need to construct it something like this:

```
x[np.where((x[:,0] == 2) | (x[:,0] == 4))]
```

Since this doesn't scale well, you might instead want to try doing it in a `for` loop:

```
good_row = ()
good_values = [2,4]
for val in good_values:
    good_row = np.append(good_row,np.where(x[:,0] == val))

print x[good_row]
```